# arm cortex a57 32 bit pointers in 64 bit

Tags: c++, arm

for my project, I using arm cortex a57 using clang.
is there a way to force the pointers to use 32-bit.

does the -mx32 even work under arm ?

Comment: If your project is a bare-metal one, you may try using clang support for the ilp32 ABI.

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/Arm64ilp32Port

Comment: this is for Nintendo Switch with unreal engine. as I was looking at flags to clang. as I trying to save memory over 64 bit vs 32 bit pointers

Comment: then use `-m32` which compiles 32-bit code. `-mx32` is x32abi which is completely irrelevant for ARM. But 32-bit code might be slower so better use arm64ilp32 if Nintendo Switch has a 64-bit kernel